# Kotlin/JS missing fun when compiled

Tags: javascript, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I am trying to compile Kotlin to JavaScript.
It is used from JavaScript project as npm module.

For example, when I wrote a Class like the one below, I can't see a method like fun hoge (fuga: SomeClass) from JavaScript. It will be undefined.

Enviroment

- Kotlin 1.5.31
- gradle 7.0.2

Fuga.kt

```
package com.example

class Fuga {
  fun hoge(someClass: SomeClass) {
     // Do something
  }

  fun hoge2() = "Hello"
}
```

JavaScript(Typescript) Project

```
import F from "npm_module";

const v = new F.com.example.Fuga();

console.log(v.hoge2()); // displayed Hello

v.hoge(someClass); // hoge is undefined
```

Why missing `hoge(someClass)` ?
How can `hoge(someClass)` be referenced from a JavaScript Project?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Missing function `hoge(someClass)` was renamed when build to js.
For example, `hoge_xyz$`.

missing function `hoge (someClass)` was renamed when build to js.

For example, `hoge_xyz $`

By using `@JsName`, I was able to refer to it with the intended name from Js without being renamed.

```
package com.example

class Fuga {

  @JsName("hoge")
  fun hoge(someClass: SomeClass) {
     // Do something
  }

  fun hoge2() = "Hello"
}
```